# Specific Permutations

Tags: python

My program is getting two lists. These are:

```
p=[x1,x2,x3]
q=[y1,y2,y3]
```

(Possible entries are just 0 and 1) Then it should give me the following lists:

```
[x1,x2,y3]
[x1,y2,x3]
[y1,x2,x3]
[y1,y2,x3]
[y1,x2,y3]
[x1,y2,y3]
```

So the entries cannot change the position of the list. Thats why simple permutations doesn't work for me. After that the program should check, if the list `t=[c1,c2,c3]` is a combination of p and q and if yes how often. But I think the second part isn't a problem for me.

Comment: It's hard to guess how those 'permutations' should be generated. There should be a rule, not only an example.

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve? The restriction to only 0,1 values makes me wonder if there's some better approach to solving the underlying problem.

Comment: Looks OK to me, just randomly pick a element from either `q` or `p`.

Comment: The underlying problem is, that I have to check if third list can be a combination of the first two and how often. The program is then doing that many million times, so it should be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that?

```
from itertools import product

p=['x1','x2','x3']
q=['y1','y2','y3']

for t in product(*zip(p,q)):
    print(t)
```

output:

```
('x1', 'x2', 'x3')
('x1', 'x2', 'y3')
('x1', 'y2', 'x3')
('x1', 'y2', 'y3')
('y1', 'x2', 'x3')
('y1', 'x2', 'y3')
('y1', 'y2', 'x3')
('y1', 'y2', 'y3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create a new list, with either the element from `q` or from `p`, of the same index, here we go:

```
In [94]:

import itertools
import numpy as np
[list(np.where(item, p, q)) for item in itertools.product(*[[0,1],]*3)]
Out[94]:
[['y1', 'y2', 'y3'],
 ['y1', 'y2', 'x3'],
 ['y1', 'x2', 'y3'],
 ['y1', 'x2', 'x3'],
 ['x1', 'y2', 'y3'],
 ['x1', 'y2', 'x3'],
 ['x1', 'x2', 'y3'],
 ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']]
```